# Grab the highest date inside of an array of entities.

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, higher-order-functions

I have the following array :

```
  let messages = (fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects as! [Message])
```

essentially, each element in this array is of the entity Message, where each Message has 5 core data attributes. Notably, the attribute I care about in this case is timestamp which is of type `NSDate` !!!!!!. I want to grab the message with the maximum date inside of this array using the reduce function. Please do not suggest to sort the messages first. I'am trying to avoid that.  Thank you !

Comment: If you are only interested in the object with the "highest date" then you can configure the fetch request accordingly (add a sort descriptor and restrict the number of fetched items to one). If you already have the array then `max(by: )` with a custom comparator can be used.  It would be interesting to know why  you want to use  `reduce`.

Comment: hey Martin R, how would I use max(by: ) in this case. I cannot figure out the syntax. Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you would want to use reduce, but I think this will work and fits with what you are looking for (assuming Swift 3):

```
let result = messages.max(by: {$0.timeStamp < $1.timeStamp})
```